# Menu always on top when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to make the menu to be always on the top when scrolling down the page but the heading that is above the menu to hide. I would like only the menu that is in div tag with id="fixed-div" to stay on the top and the other menu to hide.
I want the menu to pull up and stay fixed on the top of the page like in this site: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #fcede0;
 height: 900px;
}

#my-logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -10px;
 top: -25px;
 z-index: -1;
}

#page-title {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #22117a;
}

#inner-title {
 padding-left: 120px;
 padding-right: 70px;
}

body div img::selection, #inner-title::selection, #menu-up li a::selection, #menu-down li a::selection, body div article a img::selection, footer table tr td div::selection, footer a::selection{
 color: #ef4810;
 background-color: lightblue;
}

#menu-up{
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #ef4810;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#menu-down {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 text-align: right;
 background-color: #ef4810;
 padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#menu-up  li{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 20px; 
 width: 200px;
}

#menu-down  li {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 15px;  
 width: 250px;
}

#menu-up li a:link, #menu-down li a:link, #menu-up li a:visited, #menu-down li a:visited {
 display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #22117a;
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#menu-down li a:link, #menu-down li a:visited {
 color: #972d09;
}

#menu-up li a:hover, #menu-down li a:hover {
 display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 /*background-color:red;*/
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.HTML-CSS-logo {
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 10px black;
 border-radius: 40px;
}

#HTML-article, #CSS-article {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 100px;
 padding-right: 100px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}

#div-article {
 padding-top: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.HTML-CSS-logo:hover {
 -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
 filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="title" content="Сайт за електронно обучение по HTML5 и CSS3">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, CSS3, обучение, електронно обучение, самоучител">
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5 и CSS3 обучение">
  <meta name="author" content="Иванка Янкулова">
  <meta name="copyright" content="Иванка Янкулова">
  <!--<meta name="pubdate" content="2017-12-21">-->
  
  <title>HTML5 и CSS3 обучение</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <div id="page-title">
    <img id="my-logo" src="images/logo2.png" alt="Лого" title="Лого" />
    <div id="inner-title">Сайт за електронно обучение по HTML5 и CSS3</div>
   </div>
  </header>
  
  <div id="fixed-div">
   <nav>
    <ul id="menu-up">
     <li id="home-button" class="icon-bar">
      <a href="#" title="Начало" alt="Начало"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="" title="HTML5" alt="HTML5">HTML5</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="" title="CSS3" alt="CSS3">CSS3</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href=""title="Разработки" alt="Разработки">Разработки</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="" title="Справки" alt="Справки"> Справки</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 
  <nav>
   <ul id="menu-down">
    <li>
     <a href="" title="Полезни връзки" alt="Полезни връзки">Полезни връзки</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="" title="Препоръки за сайта" alt="Препоръки за сайта">Препоръки и забележки</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="" title="Препоръки за сайта" alt="Препоръки за сайта">Информация за сайта</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="" title="Контакти" alt="Контакти">Контакти</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div id="div-article">
   <article id="HTML-article">
    <a href="">
     <img class="HTML-CSS-logo" src="images/HTML-logo.png" alt="HTML5" title="HTML5" />
    </a>
   </article>
   <article id="CSS-article">
    <a href="">
     <img class="HTML-CSS-logo" src="images/CSS-logo.png" alt="CSS3" title="CSS3" />
    </a>
   </article>
  </div>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud listen the event of window scroll, using js control #menu-up's position be fixed or static

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    *{color:#fff;padding:0;margin:0;}
    .m-header{height: 68px;background: #ff00ff;}
    .m-nav{height: 44px;width:100%;background: #0026ff;}
    .m-main{height: 1500px;background: #73ff00;line-height: 200px;}
    .m-fixed{position: fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:3;}
    .pt44{padding-top:44px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="m-header">I'm header</div>
    <div class="m-nav">I'm the nav</div>
    <div class="m-main">I'm main content</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var oNav = $('.m-nav');
    var oMain = $('.m-main');
    var nNavTop = oNav.offset().top;
    var sNavTop= 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        sNavTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(sNavTop >= nNavTop){
        oNav.addClass('m-fixed');
        oMain.addClass('pt44');
    }else{
        oNav.removeClass('m-fixed');
        oMain.removeClass('pt44');
    }
    });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what `position: sticky` exists for.

Comment: when `#menu-up`  is  changed to fixed  `#div-article` and  `#menu-down`  need a padding-top

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed` css rule to your css code of your menu

like this:

```
#menu-up{
position: fixed;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ef4810;
padding: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I tried but then there is a space between the top of the page and the beginning of the menu and this breaks down my design

Comment: I want the menu to pull up and stay fixed on the top of the page

Comment: like @zb22 said, add `position:fixed` with `top: 0` and `left: 0`. It should stay on top of the page. What do you mean there is space between the top of the pge and the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#fixed-div
{
  position:fixed;
}
```